# How to add text to a search array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Function code that searches for a certain string in a cell and returns an output based on what is there. I had it working perfectly for values that are only numbers, but now when I try to use the same format to add a string that includes text, it doesn't seem to work.

I tried adding quotes around the array values but that doesn't seem to do the trick...

```
Function CalcValue(ByVal arg_sText As String) As String

    Dim aSearchValues() As Variant
    aSearchValues = Array(650, 750, 850, 1150, 1650, 2050)
    Dim bSearchValues() As Variant
    bSearchValues = Array("2R", "4R", "5R", "C##", "DR##", "N##", "NR##")

    Dim vSearchVal As Variant
    For Each vSearchVal In aSearchValues
        If InStr(1, arg_sText, vSearchVal, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            CalcValue = "Dozer"

        End If
    Next vSearchVal

    Dim wSearchVal As Variant
    For Each wSearchVal In bSearchValues
        If InStr(1, arg_sText, wSearchVal, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            CalcValue = "Draper"

        End If
    Next wSearchVal



    CalcValue = "TLB"

End Function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add `Exit Function` so that when a match is found it immediately stops and outputs the results.  Otherwise it will just always result in `TLB` because no exit was specified:

```
Function CalcValue(ByVal arg_sText As String) As String

    Dim aSearchValues() As Variant
    aSearchValues = Array(650, 750, 850, 1150, 1650, 2050)
    Dim bSearchValues() As Variant
    bSearchValues = Array("2R", "4R", "5R", "C##", "DR##", "N##", "NR##")

    Dim vSearchVal As Variant
    For Each vSearchVal In aSearchValues
        If InStr(1, arg_sText, vSearchVal, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            CalcValue = "Dozer"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next vSearchVal

    Dim wSearchVal As Variant
    For Each wSearchVal In bSearchValues
        If LCase(arg_sText) Like "*" & LCase(wSearchVal) & "*" Then
            CalcValue = "Draper"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wSearchVal

    'No match found
    CalcValue = "TLB"

End Function
```

Also note that for the text searches, because you need to match digits, use the `Like` operator instead of `InStr`, as shown.

Comment: I see, the `#` are actually supposed to represent ANY digit

Comment: @aMadNoob See updated answer.  The `Like` operator will match digits.